# Lost uCommerce interface within Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, umbraco-ucommerce

I am developing a web application using SiteCore 8 and uCommerce.  To configure uCommerce I go through Sitecore and load the uCommerce interface.  This morning I tried to load the uCommerce interface in the normal way, i.e logged into Sitecore and loaded uCommerce, but got nothing more than a white screen in Sitecore.  Looking at the browser console I can see 2 different 500 errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   http://local.myapp.co.uk/ucommerceapi/Content/undefined/RootNode
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   http://local.myapp.co.uk/ucommerceapi/Localization/TranslatedStrings
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   http://local.myapp.co.uk/ucommerceapi/Content/tree/RootNode Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

If I click on the url in the error I get a page that displays:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: EndpointHost.Config
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: EndpointHost.Config
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   EndpointHost.Config]
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: ServiceStack: AppHost does not exist or
>   has not been initialized. Make sure you have created an AppHost and
>   started it with 'new AppHost().Init();' in your Global.asax
>   Application_Start()]
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory..cctor()
>   +836
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory' threw
>   an exception.]
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory..ctor()
>   +0
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +256    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +14297981
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +198    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +28
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +83    System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String
>   type) +57    System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +94
>   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +375    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

I have tried recreating the `Global.asax`,  I have tried replacing all the sitecore folders:

1. `sitecore`
2. `sitecore modules`
3. `sitecore_files`

   and the `App_Config` folder using files from a colleagues machine that is working fine but not luck.  I can copy my colleagues solution to my PC and it works fine (except he has none of the work I have done)

Can anyone throw any light on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this problem.  I deleted the website from IIS then recreated it and the problem has gone away.  I have no idea why this has fixed the issue, as I have changed nothing in IIS for days.